# Default size of html5 custom elements (polymer)

Tags: css, html, height, polymer, width

Is it possible to define a default size of html5 custom elements? (using polymer)

For example, I have an arrow control, which size can be set. If no width or height is set, we should use default sizes!

Answer (score 0):

In polymer 1.0 and above you can use both custom css [properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#xscope-styling-details) and [mixins](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#custom-css-mixins), both of which allow default values:

```
:root {
  width: var(--my-arrow-control-width, 24px);
  height: var(--my-arrow-control-height, 24px); 
}
```

or using [mixins](http://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-apply-rule/#defining)

```
:root {
  --toolbar-theme: {
    background-color: hsl(120, 70%, 95%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid var(--theme-color late);
  };
  --toolbar-title-theme: {
    color: green;
  };
}

.toolbar {
  @apply(--toolbar-theme);
}
.toolbar > .title {
  @apply(--toolbar-title-theme);
}
```